# Option to display Featured Image, or not

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Wordpress 4.3.1

Hi,

this is my first post at stackoverflow and I hope I did everything right.

I need a function that allows to output the Featured Image, or not. Just not uploading an image is no option, because the thumbnail next the excerpts is needed in any case.

The following combinations are needed:

1. Thumbnail and Featured Image are identical
2. Thumbnail and first image in the article are different
3. Thumbnail and no Featured Image

I need the function for case 2 and 3. In case 2, the Featured Image will be integrated via the editor.

I have already found this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-featured-image/

However, that solves the task only with CSS:

```
.has-post-thumbnail img.wp-post-image{ display: none; }
```

But I would like that the picture is not even putted out and loaded in the Browser.

I have the following solution found on the net. It is working so far that the checkbox is shown inside the Featured Image box and it also saves the state if it is checked, or not, after updating the article. However, the Featured Image continues to be output and I don't understand what is going wrong.

Here is the code that I copied to the functions.php:

```
/**
 * Adds a checkbox to the featured image metabox.
 *
 * @param string $content
 */
  
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'optional_featured_image', 10, 2 );
/**
 * Add a 'hide the featured image' checkbox to the Featured Image area
 */
function optional_featured_image( $content, $post_ID ) {

    $content .= '<div class="hide-feat-image">';
    // add our nonce field
    $content .= wp_nonce_field( 'display_featured_image_nonce', 'display_featured_image_nonce', true, false );
    // create our checkbox
    $content .= '
    <input style="margin: 5px;" type="checkbox" id="display-featured-image" name="display_featured_image" '. checked( get_post_meta( $post_ID, 'display_featured_image', true ), true, false ) .' value="1"/>
    <label for="display-featured-image">Hide on post page?</label>
    ';
    $content .= '</div><!-- hide-feat-image -->';
    // return our appended $content
    return $content;
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_optional_featured_image' );
/**
 * Save our 'hide the featured image' checkbox to the Featured Image area
 */
function save_optional_featured_image( $post_id ) {

    if (
        // check nonce
        !isset( $_POST['display_featured_image_nonce'] )
        || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['display_featured_image_nonce'], 'display_featured_image_nonce')
        // make sure user is allowed to edit posts
        || !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id )
    )
        return;

    // sanitize our input to yes or no
    $display = isset( $_POST["display_featured_image"] ) && $_POST["display_featured_image"] ? true : false;
    // update our post
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'display_featured_image', $display );
}
```

And here's the WP snippet, I use at the template for the output:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('header-image'); ?>
```

I'm grateful for any advice! Thank you in advance for your effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I'd check in the database that this 'optional_featured_image' parameter is actually being set by your code. Check the `prefix_postmeta` table and lookup for the post you're editing.

When the template is output you need to have a conditional to check for this 'display_featured_image' parameter you've setup. Otherwise `the_post_thumbnail()` will always display.

Try this code in your template:

```
<?php
$optional_featured_image = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'display_featured_image', true);
if( !$optional_featured_image )
    the_post_thumbnail('header-image');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, James! Unfortunatley I could not find the `prefix_postmeta` table. Which is the best way to get there, inside the phpMyAdmin? Anyway, I experimented with your code snippet and had a partial success. When I use it with `display_featured_image` instead of your recommended `optional_featured_image`, the function works, but conversely. When checked, the Featured Image is shown, and when not it isn't. Would be not bad so far, but the Featured Image should be shown by default.

Comment: Edited my answer. I must have misread. 'Prefix' is by default 'wp', you set this when you install WordPress. So most likely the table name is 'wp_postmeta'. Yes phpMyAdmin is a good choice. It sounds like that db entry is going in fine anyway.

Comment: In the wp_postmeta table the entry exists. The value is 1, when the Checkbox is checked and shows nothing when it is not and it is not checked by default, as expected. But the article is not shown the Featured image by default, right now. How can I get this the other way round? The label of the checkbox is "Hide on post page?", so the function should hide the Featured Image when clicked, and not when not clicked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Add the exclamation mark in the if statement as I have. This denotes 'if $optional_featured_image is NOT true execute the code within'. By default the variable would be false as user leaves the box unchecked and the image then displays.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem could you please mark the question as resolved?